# Representation-finitness and Ext^1

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra

Given a non-local selfinjective connected quiver algebra A with indecomposable module M with $Ext^{1}(M,M) \neq 0$. Can $B=End_A(A \oplus M)$ be representation-finite? The answer is no in case $A$ is additionally symmetric.